# Adding products on the fly to order

Tags: java, broadleaf-commerce

I would like to add products to cart on the fly. This means the products to add are not stored in the database and doesn't have to. But when I take a look into the cart endpoint how items added to an order the class `org.broadleafcommerce.core.order.service.call.OrderItemRequestDTO` requires a product id.

So this means I've to override `blCatalogService` which would allow temporary products too? Is this all or did I forget something else to achieve the adding of products to the cart/order on the fly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OrderItem data model and services don't strictly require a SKU but many of the out of box examples do.

You should be able to override the CartEndpoint and instead of creating an OrderItemRequestDTO, create a NonDiscreteOrderItemRequestDTO.

The AddOrderItemActivity which is part of the workflow executed when an item is added checks for this type and will create an OrderItem instead of a DiscreteOrderItem or BundleOrderItem (both of which require a SKU).

Hope this helps,

Brian

Note : I work for Broadleaf